# Indent xml data fetched via request | python |

Tags: python, python-requests, python-xmlschema

I got stuck not getting how to achieve it.

Need your suggestion on this how to implement in my code

**My code :**

```
import requests

url = '....'  # not mentioning as its private 

headers_details = {
'Host' : 'axb.vttp.com',
'Accept-Encoding' : 'gzip,deflate',
'Accept' : '*/*'
}

parameter = { 'id' : '4566' ,'key' :'tyuo' }

rq = requests.post( url,params=parameter, headers=headers_details) 

with open('demo.xml','w') as wr:
    wr.write(rq.content)
```

My data is written to my xml file. But its not in indent format the xml data.

How to achieve the xml data in file in proper indentation format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've need to parse the xml, then serialise it with indentation.

With `lxml`:

```py
from lxml import etree
import requests

url = r"https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml"

rq = requests.get(url)

# Parse the xml
root = etree.fromstring(rq.content)

with open('demo.xml', 'wb') as wr:
    # Serialise the xml
    wr.write(etree.tostring(root, encoding="utf-8", pretty_print=True))
```

See:

- https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#fromstring
- https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#tostring

Comment: Not working the above code

Comment: Can you elaborate? Is there an error? If so, copy the traceback.

Comment: You already have data in URL in formatted way so no change once file created in my system

Comment: It works for me. You can also change the indentation by calling this before `.tostring()`: `etree.indent(root, space="        ")`. Make sure you've got the latest version of `lxml`: `pip install lxml --force`.